# How can I printf "d\xe9j\xe0 vu" as "Déjà vu" in C?

Tags: c, internationalization

I'm new at programming and currently learning i18n part of C. I had absolutely no clue how things work.

I learned that in Latin-1 encoding `\xe9` stands for é and `\xe0` stands for à. How can I tell C that it needs to translate `\xe9` to é and print it? How can `setlocale()` help in this situation?

I thought this is a common newbie question but I couldn't find anything related on Google.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("d\u00e9j\u00e0 vu\n");
```

wikipedia: [Escape Sequences in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)